can't install grub-pc after upgrading to 24.04
I upgraded to 24.04. The only problem remaining now is that grub-pc can not be installed.
I got:
Setting up grub-pc (2.12-1ubuntu7) ...
Installing for i386-pc platform.
mdadm: /dev/md does not appear to be an md device
grub-install: error: ioctl RAID_VERSION error: Inappropriate ioctl for device.
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
 installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
Updating coolwsd systemplate
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Since I have:
# df
Filesystem      1K-blocks      Used  Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs             1628216      1816    1626400   1% /run
/dev/md2       1920043304 335436508 1487000140  19% /
tmpfs             8141076         0    8141076   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5120         8       5112   1% /run/lock
/dev/md1          1011148    293728     648712  32% /boot
tmpfs             1628212       100    1628112   1% /run/user/131
tmpfs             1628212        88    1628124   1% /run/user/1001```

I tried (as root)
```# grub-install /dev/md1
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install: warning: File system `ext2' doesn't support embedding.
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.```

But when asking ```lsblk -f``` I got 
(I show only part of the output)

sda
├─sda1 linux_ra 1.2     md1       f3e919b7-e0fc-0966-03c7-b0a1bddd08d0
│ └─md1
│      ext4     1.0     boot      1c1a400e-09d2-4a0d-a2fd-8f6173774af4  633.5M    29% /boot
So, I'm lost, what should I do to install grub? 
Frederic


With old BIOS install, you always install grub to a drive like sda, never to a partition like sda1. For those with separate /boot partitions you have to mount both /boot & / to install grub. https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows  or full chroot, But be sure to mount /boot & /. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot Most other chroot examples are for UEFI with mount of ESP as all systems since 2012 are UEFI with gpt partitioning.

Thank you. One question: do I really need grub? Mine it's a rented server, I can't reformat partitioning. I don't want to install any other OS. Can I get ride of grub?

Basically yes. Grub is both the default boot loader (required) and boot menu. Since default well support in most distributions. Some like rEFInd as a UEFI boot menu. I used it from a flash drive for emergency boot There are some other boot loaders like SystemD boot and others. And old BIOS systems may boot with syslinux.

Thanks oldfred! I'll try your suggestion
Fred
